# I dont know what is wrong with my django

Tags: python, django

I dont know what is wrong, and I am desperates with no sleep int two days because of this error. I dont know where does it come from, and it wouldn let me know what did i do wrong. for your information I am learning using django with python, my version of django is 1.11 and my version of python is 2.7 . Please help me, this is what i got from my code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 68, in handle
    fail_level=getattr(checks, options['fail_level']),
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 28, in check_resolver
    warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 30, in check_resolver
    warnings.extend(check_pattern_name(pattern))
  File "/home/juunnn/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 120, in check_pattern_name
    if pattern.name is not None and ":" in pattern.name:
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```

See? it would not let me know where is my fault is.

Comment: The problem is in your url patterns. Please show your `urls.py`.

Comment: You say you are using Python 2.7, but the traceback shows `python3.5`.

Comment: id that bad ? @Alasdair?

Comment: It's always a good idea to know which version you are using ;) The future of Python is Python 3, so if your project works with 3.5 then stick with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error suggests that you have forgotten quotes when naming a URL pattern.

For example you have `name=my_view`,

```
url('^my-url/$', my_view, name=my_view)
```

when you should use a string `name='my_view'`:

```
url('^my-url/$', my_view, name='my_view')
```

Comment: Oke that is the problem, thank you. I could not see it, because I am not used to python yet. I really thakn you btw.